# How to check whether the youtube url has username or channel?

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to check the youtube url is username or channelid ?
for example https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC--------hdch . how to check?

Comment: if the url has user i will continue for user. if the url has channel i will extract channel id after link. pls help

Comment: u want to check that through code or just ingeneral?

Comment: In code java or kotlin

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the url contains the string `user` for User and `channel` for Channel.

```
String url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa"

if(url.contains("/channel/")){
   //url is a channel url 
}else if(url.contains("/user/")){
   //url is a user url
}
```

Comment: thanks Rafsanjani. this is valid method ? this condition satisfies in all scenarios ?

Comment: @suryac yes it does

Comment: This will break if the username contains “channel” or a channel’s name contains “user”.

Comment: Sorry, was on my phone earlier. Put slashes around the text so it will exactly match that part of the URL. `url.contains("/channel/")`. You can also do `"/channel/" in url`

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is that you have to verify that there is a link to user or a channel directly after the youtube address,

```kotlin
val url: String = "https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa"

if(url.contains("/channel/")){
   //url is a channel url 
}else if(url.contains("/user/")){
   //url is a user url
}
```

Here I didn't used to check if the string contains `youtube.com/user/` because some urls may have `youtu.be/user/` which is valid and offical address, so just checking that there is forward slash before and after the identifier it makes sure that it'll work as expected!

**EDIT1:**

OP wants a regex solution so:

```kotlin
val regex = Regex("""(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(user|channel)""")
val result = regex.find("https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa")
when(result!!.groupValues[1]){
    "user" -> //code
    "channel" -> //code
    else -> {} //or replace {} with code
}
```

**EDIT2:**

You could use this expression to get the information about the url

```kotlin
val regex = Regex("""(?:https:\/\/)*(?:www\.)*(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(user|channel)\/(\w+)""")
val result = regex.find("https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa")!!
when(result.groupValues[2]){
    "user" -> //code
    "channel" -> //code
    else -> {} //or replace {} with code
}

println(result.groupValues[0]) //https://www.youtube.com/user/aaaaaaaa
println(result.groupValues[1]) //youtube.com
println(result.groupValues[2]) //user
println(result.groupValues[3]) //aaaaaaaa
```

**EDIT3:**
As OP suggested this does not work for a symbol (non word literal) hence, instead of `/w+` you could use `.+`

So the finalized regex would be

```regex
(?:https:\/\/)*(?:www\.)*(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(user|channel)\/(.+)
```

Comment: Why the double slashes? That makes this fail.

Comment: Sorry i just assumed them backslash(escaping slash) for no reason, thanks for correction!

Comment: Thanks @Animesh Sahu. Any regex method is available for this problem (have to verify that there is a link to user or a channel) ?

Comment: @suryac check the regex solution!

Comment: Animesh Sahu Thank you very much... Solved.Regex Pattern is working now

Comment: Hi animesh , if channel has , ex: channel/UC-uue99 if - (hypen comes) the  pattern not match. why ?

Comment: suryac sorry for the misunderstanding, i was hoping for non-symbolics as used in question, but i updated the answer with better regex which could do this!